# Trigger file upload from outside an upload component in plotly

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dashboard in Plotly that needs two specific but separate files to be uploaded. I have two separate components today (very simplified, but this is to give you the gist):

```py
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(html.Button('Upload File 1')),
    dcc.Upload(html.Button('Upload File 2')),
])
```

This is all good if I force the user to click on one button at a time. But how can I get it so that the upload prompt for file 2 opens automatically when the upload of file 1 is completed so the user don't have to click the button for file 2 explicitly?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input


app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Upload(id="upload1", children=html.Button("Upload File 1")),
    dcc.Upload(id="upload2", children=html.Button(id="btn-upload2", children="Upload File 2")),
    dcc.Store(id="dummy-output")
])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(filename) {
        document.getElementById('btn-upload2').click()
    }
    """,
    Output('dummy-output', 'data'),
    Input('upload1', 'filename'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True
```

The idea of the code above is to use a [clientside callback](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks) so we can simulate a click on the second upload button when the user has uploaded a new file using the first upload component.

*I would very much advise against doing this from a user perspective though. I think it's very confusing to have one file upload popup open after submitting another. Is it clear to a user what they're uploading when the second popup opens? I'd keep it simple and let the user click the buttons themselves.*